# Angularjs , Spring Boot PUT not supported with spring security

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

Angular controller function

```
$scope.updatePatient = function() {
            var patient = new patientUpdateService({id:"15", name:"m",lastname:"s"});
            patient.$update();
}
```

Angular service

```
.factory("patientUpdateService", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/updatepatient", {id: "@id"}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
})
```

Spring boot controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/updatepatient/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
      @ResponseBody
      public Patients update(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody @Valid Patients patient) {
       return patientrep.save(patient);

}
```

I am making simple crud operation application using angularjs and springboot but i am getting following error :

in Angular :  PUT http://localhost:8080/updatepatient?id=15 405 (Method Not Allowed)

in Tomcat : o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'PUT' not supported

I am using CRUDRepository ; Get, POST , DELETE are working properly .

Comment: Read the error message. Angular sends the request to `updatepatient?id=15`. But your spring controller is mapped to `/updatepatient/15`.

Comment: So in spring controller  , what request mapping should i put , i tried value="/updatepatient?id={id}"   , but it is not working

Comment: Thanks a lot its working now  , in angular controller i change to /updatepatient/:id"

Answer (score 0):

Angular is sending query params instead of pathvariables, to map query params you have to use the @RequestParam annotation, here is an example

```
@RequestMapping(value="/group/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public MetaListDto<UserDto> findUsersForGroup(@RequestParam(value="id", required=false)  Long groupId,@RequestParam(value="offset", required=false)  Integer offset,@RequestParam(value="limit", required=false)  Integer limit)  {
```

Hope it helps